# Autodoc extension support for Markdown output in Sphinx

Tags: markdown, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am using sphinx for auto-doc generation for my project.I have already tried generating html which works fine.
I would like to generate markdowns with docstrings loaded in it from classes imported via 'autodoc' extension. 
So far I have used 'recommonmark' and 'sphinx-markdown-builder' extensions for the same.
I haven't found a way so far where these markdown extensions support 'autodoc'.
I could generate normal markdown, but I only see class names rather than
docstrings of all functions.
Can anybody please help me with it?

Comment: Please provide an example of your source reST files and relevant sections of your conf.py. Have you also generated the stub files first with [`sphinx-apidoc`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-apidoc.html)?

Comment: Content from index.rst
`Code
==================
- AbstractClient::
.. autoclass:: sdir.client.AbstractClient
   :members:
   :private-members:
   :inherited-members:`
And content from conf.py

`extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
    'rinoh.frontend.sphinx',
    'recommonmark'
]

# source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']
source_suffix = '.rst'`

Comment: No I haven't tried sphinx-apidoc yet.
I am using 'make markdown' command for recommonmark.
It parses index.rst, but produces index.md without links and auto docstrings.

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Update your answer instead. What makes you think that markdown supports the features you want? When you realize it doesn't work, then try something that does work, like what I suggested.